# Getting trouble in Login Page 3-Tire architecture

Tags: c#, database-connection, 3-tier

Bussiness Access Layer :

```
    public static int login(string userlogin, string pwdlogin)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        int id = 0;
        string selectstr = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Registration WHERE UserName = '" + userlogin.Trim() + "' AND Password = '" + pwdlogin.Trim() + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = selectstr;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        id = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd = null;
        con.Close();
        return id;
    }
```

Login.cs

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = BusinessAccessLayer.login(userlogin.Text.Trim(), pwdlogin.Text.Trim());
        if (id > 0)
        {
            message.Text = " valid";
        }
        else
        {
            message.Text = "in valid";
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You've shown us the code, but haven't told us *anything* about what's wrong. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list. (Admittedly I can see four significant problems just browsing through it, but I don't know whether any of those are related to what you're seeing...)

Comment: every time its showing invalid user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)  is used for For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements.
For SELECT statements, use [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

```
public static int login(string userlogin, string pwdlogin)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        int id = 0;
        string selectstr = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Registration WHERE UserName = '" + userlogin.Trim() + "' AND Password = '" + pwdlogin.Trim() + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = selectstr;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
               id++; 
        }
        cmd = null;
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
        return id;
}
```

Comment: That's going to return "the number of users with the given username and password" rather than the *ID* of the right user. It also doesn't address any of the rest of the horrible problems in the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The if statement provided by the OP is only check if `id > 0` or not...if `id > 0` then it's a valid so i simply the code with `id++`.

Comment: @IswantoSan: That's what they're *currently* doing - but given that the name is `id` it's clearly meant to be the ID of the user, not just a Boolean decision. I suspect the OP was originally just *testing* the login code, and will then use the actual user ID later.

Comment: @yash: Do you *really* not want the user ID? If so, you shouldn't *call* it `id` as a variable name. Make your code say what it means - if you're only after a Boolean result, you should declare the method to return `bool` rather than `int`.

Comment: @JonSkeet:I'll edited my answer after the OP answer your question above

Comment: @IswantoSan: Are you going to point out the horrible security flaws and potential for resource leaks at the same time?

Comment: @IswantoSan: Well, SQL injection *and* the fact that he appears to be storing the password in plain text. (And the lack of `using` statements.) See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, there are multiple things wrong here:

1) You should use `using` statements to make sure you close your connection and command even if exceptions are thrown

2) You should use parameterized SQL instead of putting the values directly into your SQL statement, to avoid SQL Injection Attacks

3) You appear to be storing passwords in plain text. **Don't do that.** Use a salted hash or something similar (ideally something slow to compute).

4) You're ignoring .NET naming conventions; methods should be in PascalCase

5) Your SQL never looks at any field which appears to be related to the user ID. It's not clear what you expect `ExecuteNonQuery` to return, but if you want the actual ID, you'll need to refer to it in the SQL. (Even if initially you just want to know whether or not the user's password is valid, I strongly suspect that at some point you'll want to user the real user ID, so you should make your code return it. If you *really* only want to know whether or not the password is valid, you should change the method's return type to `bool`.)

6) You're using `ExecuteNonQuery` when your command clearly *is* a query. Either use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) or [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead. (`ExecuteNonQuery` is meant for insert, delete and update statements, and it returns you the number of rows affected by the command.)

So something like:

```
public static int Login(string user, string password)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select Id, PasswordHash from logins where Username=@Username";
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user;

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteRead())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    string hash = reader.GetString(1);
                    // TODO: Hash provided password with the same salt and compare
                    // results
                    if (CheckPassword(password, hash))
                    {
                        return id;
                    }
                }
                return 0; // Or use an int? return type and return null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .ExecuteNonQuery if you want a result. Use .ExecuteReader.

```
public static int login(string userlogin, string pwdlogin)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
    con.Open();
    int id = 0;
    string selectstr = "SELECT UserId FROM Registration WHERE UserName = '" +    userlogin.Trim() + "' AND Password = '" + pwdlogin.Trim() + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = selectstr;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    id = reader.GetInt32("UserId");

    reader.Close();
    con.Close();

    return id;
}
```